# Disable clipboard formatting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

When copying/pasting content into Outlook it preserves formatted code.

So if I paste content from a webpage it includes styling information. Can this be removed?

Up to now I paste the content into editor that removes formatting (such as notepad) and then re-copy / paste into outlook.

Comment: I wish I knew why Microsoft thinks anyone would _ever_ want to paste text with the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste it like normal, and then Word (Outlook's default editor) will offer you a little popup, in which you can click to get different paste options, including "Keep Text Only", which will keep the text but eliminate styling and other elements.

[image]

[picture source](https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/word-2010-keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-unformatted-text/)

Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to Paste, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to open the paste dropdown, <kbd>T</kbd> to choose "Keep Text Only" (it's CTRL, release, then T; not Ctrl+T).

For related info see this other SU question:

[What is the keyboard shortcut for Keep Text Only in Outlook?](https://superuser.com/questions/343268/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-keep-text-only-in-outlook)

To have Outlook paste in plain text by default:

- Open Outlook.
- File -> Options -> Mail
- Click "Editor Options..."
- Advanced Tab -> Scroll down to "Cut, Copy, and Paste"
- Change "Pasting from other programs" to "Keep Text Only".

[image]

You can adjust the other options for paste sources as you see fit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Paste using right-click menu. You'll find the paste icon with **"A"** character on it in **Paste Options**. This will remove the formatting.